# impossible to evaluate dir while copying in loop

Tags: linux, loops, copy, command, cp

im executing this command :

```
for i in `ls -lrt --full-time /tmp/source/ | grep "2018-11" | awk '{print $9}' `; do cp /tmp/source/$i* /tmp/data/; done
```

but i'm getting this error :

> cp: impossible d'évaluer
>   « /tmp/source/\033[01;32mpart-r-00015-c1055bf2-3985-4e44-9c2e-af8eb460c471.snappy.parquet\033[0m\033[K** »: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type

but the files is :

> part-r-00015-c1055bf2-3985-4e44-9c2e-af8eb460c471.snappy.parquet

the command is adding extra : \033[01;32m and \033[0m\033[K**

but i don't know why ?

Thanks

output for

```
ls -lrt --full-time /tmp/source/ | grep "2018-11" | awk '{print $9}'
```

is :

```
part-r-00018-28ce784e-2519-4552-8d29-83074be49e84.snappy.parquet* 
part-r-00016-28ce784e-2519-4552-8d29-83074be49e84.snappy.parquet* 
part-r-00021-28ce784e-2519-4552-8d29-83074be49e84.snappy.parquet* 
part-r-00017-28ce784e-2519-4552-8d29-83074be49e84.snappy.parquet* 
part-r-00022-28ce784e-2519-4552-8d29-83074be49e84.snappy.parquet* 
part-r-00023-28ce784e-2519-4552-8d29-83074be49e84.snappy.parquet*
```

Comment: can you provide the output for ls -lrt --full-time /tmp/source/ | grep "2018-11" | awk '{print $9}'

Comment: That's the file name - the control characters (the extra stuff) are not shown in some programs.

Comment: output for ls -lrt --full-time /tmp/source/ | grep "2018-11" | awk '{print $9}'      is : 
part-r-00018-28ce784e-2519-4552-8d29-83074be49e84.snappy.parquet*
part-r-00016-28ce784e-2519-4552-8d29-83074be49e84.snappy.parquet*
part-r-00021-28ce784e-2519-4552-8d29-83074be49e84.snappy.parquet*
part-r-00017-28ce784e-2519-4552-8d29-83074be49e84.snappy.parquet*
part-r-00022-28ce784e-2519-4552-8d29-83074be49e84.snappy.parquet*
part-r-00023-28ce784e-2519-4552-8d29-83074be49e84.snappy.parquet*

Comment: there are really  `*` chars in the output of `ls -lrt ...` ?

Comment: yes there are really * chars in the output of ls -lrt ...

Comment: ah, most likely the`\033[01;32m and \033[0m\033[K**` is generated by the $LS_COLORS env-var. You can turn them off with `ls -lrt --colors=none` or similar. Consult your local `man ls` or `info ls` for the exact syntax for your system. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account that ["ls to output sorted filenames and operate on the results using e.g. awk [...] cannot be made robust"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003), and trying to guess what you want, does that command help you?

```
find /tmp/source/ -type f -newermt "2018-11-1" \! -newermt "2018-12-1" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do cp -a "$filename" /tmp/data/; done
```

Note: That `find` command tries to find something that was modified in november 2018 (the "mt" of "newermt" refers to "modification time" and "reference is interpreted directly as a time").